# Survival analysis to get DROP OUT rates

Tags: r, survival-analysis, exposure

Ciao, I have data on student drop-outs and I am aiming to conduct a survival analysis I believe to examine or predict the probability of drop out at a given grade. The challenge however is I want to group grades together so for example (7,8) (9,10) (11,12)

Here is my replicating example. This is the data I have now:

```
data <- data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  GRADE=c(9,10,11,12,7,8,9,10,9,10,11,12),
                  DROPOUT=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1))
```

I made the data tall so for example STUDENT=1 never dropped out and STUDENT=2 dropped out in the 9th grade and STUDENT=3 dropped out in the 12th grade.

Now here is my basic survival analytic approach

```
attach(data)
survivalmodel <- Surv(time=GRADE,event=DROPOUT)
```

Do I need time2 = ? Could you say how important it is to have this and how it is possibly measured? I am self-taught and still reading.

So my question is how do I get drop out probabilities for GRADE bands (7,8) (9,10) (11,12) so to ultimately have a probability of student drop out in GRADES 7 and 8 separate for GRADES 9 and 10 separate for GRADES 11 and 12.

Comment: Can you replace the values, e.g., with `2*ceiling(data$GRADE/2)`? (Realize that you don't have to store this back in `GRADE`, you can call it `GRADE2` and only use `GRADE` in reporting.

Comment: @r2evans I am not 100 percent sure I understand what you are saying. Basically on what I read I want to estimate probabilities for DROPOUT for the grouped GRADES but this is troubling to me because for example STUDENT 1  was in grades 9 10 11 and 12. I read this is called exposure yet to calculate it is a mystery to me.

Comment: Are you looking to find the total dropout period across the grade 7-8 period? In that case I'd think you could first remove the rows for odd-numbered years and then run the analysis.

Comment: Basically the drop-out rate for the GRADE groups.

Answer (score 1):

`time` (what you were calling `time1`) should be the first observed grade attended. (I'm assuming that for any given school there would be new students transferring in.) `time2` should be either the grade at which a dropout occurs or 12. Event should be as you have it, except you should not have duplicates. Line 8 should be deleted. You should construct a new dataframe that has 4 columns and three rows (one for each student.)

```
sdat <- read.table(text="STUDENT start GRADE DROPOUT
1 9 12 0
2 7 9 1
3 9 12 1", header=TRUE)
sdat
# NEVER use attach, but especially never with survival pkg functions

coxph( Surv(time=start, time2=GRADE, event=DROPOUT)~. , data=sdat[-1])
Call:  coxph(formula = Surv(time = start, time2 = GRADE, event = DROPOUT) ~ 
    ., data = sdat[-1])

Null model
  log likelihood= -0.6931472 
  n= 3
```